# Footnote on first page (IEEE Conference document)

Tags: footnotes, templates, ieeetran

[image]

I posted in the past, that I'm writing with an IEEE template for a conference. I want to add only one footnote on the first page. Look including image.

```
\footnote{Software Engineering 2017, Beijing, China\\Doctoral Symposium Paper}
```

But this footnote is commming up before my 1st site and has a footnumber.

I hope I didn't make it complicated.

Thanks for your efforts.

Maxi

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \else
 \fi

    \ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
      \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]    {subfig}
    \else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}
\footnote{Software Engineering 2017, Beijing, China\\Doctoral Symposium Paper}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}



\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
    \and
\IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\ and Montgomery Scott}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{Introduction}


\hfill mds

\hfill December 27, 2012

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here.


\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.


\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.


\section*{Acknowledgment}


The authors would like to thank...


\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: @TeXnician - MWE?

Comment: A minimal working example (basically the essence of your TeX document producing the error).

Comment: @TeXnician: Tks for the explanation :-)

Comment: `\maketitle`starts a new page so you have to put the footnote after `maketitle`.  I  can't understand your request well. Maybe the following will work: `\bgroup\def\thefootnote{}\footnote{Software Engineering 2017, Beijing, China\\Doctoral Symposium Paper}\egroup` Please note the extra line.

Comment: If you don't want a number, just use \begin{table}[b]\footnotesize ... \end{table}

Comment: It's working :-) Tks, but it should be two columns ...

Comment: Can someone tell me pls how do I edit a footnotesize for 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[12pt]
 978-1-4799-5500-8/14/\$31.00 \copyright 2014 IEEE\\ 
 Conference Name and venue
\end{minipage}} 

\IEEEpubidadjcol
 \begin{abstract}
 lorem ipsum ...
 \end{abstract}
\IEEEpubidadjcol
```

This worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE conference papers do not typically use `\IEEEpubid` and this command is locked out in conference mode. If really needed, such as for the acknowledgment of grants, issue `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` after `\documentclass`

And then write this Code:

```
\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[12pt]
 978-1-5386-0869-2/17/\$31.00 \copyright 2017 IEEE \\
 4th International Conference on Advances in Electrical Engineering 28-30 September, 2017, Dhaka, Bangladesh
\end{minipage}}
```